# Show modal based on post id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dynamically-generated, react-modal

I am working on my blog and am trying to implement Sanity. I was able to get my posts to show up with the json object returned from query with useState
I am trying to populate my React-Modal with the correct contents based on the post I have clicked with its _id or some kind of key. I simplified the code so it wouldn't be too long:

```
export default function News() {
  // Json objects stored in posts 
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  // Used to toggle Modal on and off
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  function toggleModal() {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {posts.map((posts) => (
        <div key={posts._id}>
           <h3 className="title" onClick={toggleModal}>
              {posts.title}
           </h3>
           <div">
              <a>
                <span onClick={toggleModal}>Read More</span>
              </a>
           </div>
           // Clicking on either span or a tag shows the Modal
            <Modal
               isOpen={isOpen}
               onRequestClose={toggleModal}>
               // Closes modal
              <button className="close-modal" onClick={toggleModal}>
                  <img
                    src="assets/img/svg/cancel.svg"
                    alt="close icon"/>
              </button>
              // Want to show content based on _id
              <h3 className="title">{posts.title}</h3>
              <p className="body">{posts.body}</p>
        </div>
      )
    </>
  )
}
```

Whenever I click on a certain post, it always toggles on the first object.
[Click to see gif demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFG0S.gif)

> Edit: I was able to get it to work based on the answer given

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({ isOpen: false, postId: null });

  const openModal = React.useCallback(
    (_key) => () => {
      setState({ isOpen: true, postId: _key });
    },
    []
  );

  function closeModal() {
    setState({ isOpen: false, postId: null });
  }
```

And with Modal tag I added

```
key={post.id == state.postId}
```

Now every divs and tags that renders the correct content.
**However**, I'm facing a slight issue. If I click on post[2] and it renders out post[0] content and in a blink of an eye changes to the correct content. Then when I click on post[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFG0S.gif), it renders and post[2] content and changes to the correct one. It keeps rendering the previous post. It's all in a blink of an eye, but still visible.

Comment: `{posts.map((posts) => (` => `{posts.map((post) => ` rename `posts` to `post` in parentheses. That is making problem

Comment: Hi! Although what you stated is a good thing and brought to my attention on careful naming, but it doesn't fix the problem. Each posts seen only toggles the Modal with the content on post[0].

Comment: can you share the code on codesandbox because the above code is not helping to solve the  problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest using react hooks to solve your problem.

You can pass a function to useCallback's return, you can then call your function normally in the render by passing params to it.

See more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function News() {
  // Json objects stored in posts 
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  // Used to toggle Modal on and off
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  
  // React.useCallback.
  const toggleModal = React.useCallback((id) => () => {
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
      console.log(`Post id: ${id}`);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div key={post._id}>
           <h3 className="title" onClick={toggleModal(post._id)}>
              {post.title}
           </h3>
           <div">
              <a>
                <span onClick={toggleModal(post._id)}>Read More</span>
              </a>
           </div>
           // Clicking on either span or a tag shows the Modal
            <Modal
               isOpen={isOpen}
               onRequestClose={toggleModal(post._id)}>
               // Closes modal
              <button className="close-modal" onClick={toggleModal(post._id)}>
                  <img
                    src="assets/img/svg/cancel.svg"
                    alt="close icon"/>
              </button>
              // Want to show content based on _id
              <h3 className="title">{post.title}</h3>
              <p className="body">{post.body}</p>
        </div>
      )
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Was able to tweak the code to actually make it work.  What i did is `setState({ isOpen: true, postId: _key });` in the useCallback and set `key={post._id == state.postId}` in the <Modal> tag to get it to show the correct post content. **However** I'm not sure if it's a bug or something. If I click on post[0] and close the modal and immediately open post[1], it'll very briefly show post[0] contents. When I say briefly, it's really fast but still visible.